# Kernel panic while updating to Ubuntu 16.04 from 14.04

Tags: system-installation, upgrade

I tried to update my Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 but it could not be successfully updated at once. I kept trying and now I'm getting the following message:

```
Kernel panic : not synced attempted to kill init! exit code : 0x00007f00
```

After that I tried entering grub and ran command

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Now I don't see kernel panic but also can't see my data, just the main screen saying "Ubuntu 14.05 LTS", not even icons.
I don't want to loose my data. Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/questions/811879/ubuntu-upgrade-to-16-04-kernel-panic-issue

Comment: Your install is most likely toast BTW.

Answer (score 0):

This kernel panic probably suggests that Upstart, SystemD, SysVInit, or whatever initialization program your operating system is running is corrupted.

At this point I'm afraid the easiest option is to reinstall.