# Update from 14.04 LTS to 16.04 LTS got stuck due to mysql ALTER TABLE FORCE

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, upgrade, mysql

I'm in the process of upgrading my Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 LTS.

All packages have been dowloaded and I'm at the "Installing the upgrades" step, with the "Configuring ubuntu-drivers-common (amd64)" task.

What I can see on the terminal is that the last command run was

```
Running: ALTER TABLE xxx.yyy FORCE
status: OK
```

Then nothing, it stays that way forever, it's been 15 mn. I don't know what to do and what not to do.

Any advice?

---

**Edit 1:**
I killed the VM, it was freezing my computer. Started the VM again, nothing is working, got a lot of ERROR in the console during boot. No graphic mode. I was able to start my session using tty1. (console)

I'm gonna try again after deleting everything related to mysql...

Comment: FYI we've had two questions today where people upgraded and got a kernel panic on reboot: https://askubuntu.com/questions/811905/kernel-panic-while-updating-to-ubuntu-16-04-from-14-04

Comment: I'm happy to be on a VM and to have made a snapshot "just in case" before the upgrade.